# What was the significance of changing the name of "Persia" to "Iran"?

Tags: middle-east, iran, persia

As best as I understand it, the founding of the Islamic Republic of *Iran* in 1979 was when Persia became Iran.   What was the motivation for changing the name?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This seemed to have come from Persia's freedom from the Qajars and some nationalism on the part of Germany during WWII influencing the Shah's decisions.  So it was originally changed in 1935 and not 1979, unless you are only referring to the Islamic Republic addition, which was done at the Ayatollah's will, more than likely.  The name of the country in Persian apparently was Iran so this was a natural choice for their own name.

You can find more here: [Iran Heritage site on changing name to Iran](http://www.iran-heritage.org/interestgroups/language-article5.htm)

> In 1935 the Persian government requested countries with which it had diplomatic relations to call Persia Iran, which is the name of the country in Persian. This was a grievous error based on a misdirected sense of nationalism. The suggestion for the change is said to have come from the Persian ambassador to Germany, who came under the influence of the Nazis. At the time Germany was in the grip of racial fever and cultivated good relations with nations of Aryan blood. It is said that some German friends of the ambassador persuaded him that, as with the advent of Reza Shah Persia had turned a new leaf in its history and had freed itself from the pernicious influences of Britain and Russia, whose interventions in Persian affairs had practically crippled the country under the Qajars, it was only fitting that the country be called by its own name, Iran. This would not only signal a new beginning and bring home to the world the new era in Persian history, but would also signify the Aryan race of its population, as Iran is a cognate of Aryan and derived from it

Comment: Definitely on point.  I would however, emphasize the fact that the use of the term "Persia" to refer to Iran was a western invention dating back to the Greeks.  From what I understand it was a derivation of the name of the modern western province of Fars.  Thus Reza Shah's request (which the attached article argues was in bad judgement) in 1935 to the West was for them to use the name the "Iran", as that is what its inhabitants referred to it as.

Comment: Might the European use of the word "Persia" to refer to Iran be analogous with the Roman use of the word "Palestine" to refer to the Levant? I understand that both were intended to separate (in the eyes of the Greeks and Romans) the lands from those who were currently inhabiting it. Are there other examples of such "conquerors renaming" to separate the people from the land?

Comment: I know some (Shah era) Iranian expats that insist on being referred to as "Persian" rather than Iranian. Which name you use appears to be viewed by Iranians/Persians as a *political* decision, not just an issue of taxonomy.

Comment: @dotancohen: I don't think the disassociation concept applies to Persia.

Comment: I know some people from Iran with whom I play in some internet MMORPG games who calls their country "Persia". They dislike the name "Iran".

Comment: How did you recognize their hates from long distance? And how many Iranian IDs? And how can you be sure about their nationalities? And how do history and reality depend on rumors and cheap talks more than valid sources and rational thinking? :)

Comment: Personal anecdote: the Iranians I have known (as international students in Canada) all agreed that Iran was the name of the nation-state, but Persia was the name of the region, the people, and the culture.  So they would talk about an Iranian visa, but a Persian restaurant.

Answer (score 7):

It is not true. The name [Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran) is old enough and comes from *Ayran* which means the land of [Aryans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryan) but Reza Shah suspected westerners' motives in using the name *Persia* instead of Iran and tried to change the name to Iran again.

Reza Shah had extreme nationalist ideas, and the Nazi regime cheated him and abused these feelings in the second world war. Westerners insisted in using this name to humiliate Reza Shah as he was almost their puppet and they couldn't tolerate his new nationalist ideas and attempts for independence, so they blamed him for having close relationships with the Nazi regime and wanted to remind him their own roles in increasing his power to be the king of Persia!

As an Iranian, none the westerner's attempts and Nazi plans to abuse the naming of an old big land according to their own benefits makes sense to me. To make it more clear for you, as an Iranian, my nation and I use both names without any special purpose. My nation and I do not use *Persia* to say our land was a part of west colonies, as it was not. Also we do not call our land *Iran* to say we are the best nation in the world as *Aryan* is only a name of a race in genes of many different nations from India to the Europe, equal to the other races. Surely this name doesn't have any relation to Nazi's bullshits.

I think one of oldest civilizations in the world doesn't need such ridiculous tricks. I only want to correct some your mistakes about it as it is a site for expert answers to expert questions about history and needs more researches and attention before asking a question or trying to answer it.

Comment: I really do sympathize with your agitation over this, but please consider this rationally: a lot of ancient history was written by the Greeks and Romans about *Persia* (cf. the Greco-Persian wars). It'd be absolutely ahistorical (and very confusing for scholars and students) to retroactively rewrite ancient history to be about Iran, instead of Persia. No slight or insinuation is implied by using the name Persia in its ancient historical context.

Comment: I do not know what is your mean of agitation. It is just a piece of reality. There is no need for sympathy or the other feelings. I am talking about history not imagination or a local history classroom. When you talk about world's history you have to increase your information about it by any help from everyone who can help to know more about. And a lot of ancient history was written on stones and walls of Persepolis,Pasargad,Susa and Bisotoun. I am not talking according to my own personal idea but according to the contemporary situation of my own country which my grandfathers have written it.

Comment: We are talking about history here which has been mixed with politics so there is not the matter of feelings or prejudice. It is reality nothing less,nothing more! We all are responsible about reality as the main core of history and have to protect it against distort,lie and prejudice.

Comment: Agitation as in "Emotional state of excitement or restlessness", not in the political sense. Sorry if my choice of word had an unintended double-meaning I hadn't in mind!

Comment: Well, that's the thing - when Herodotus wrote about the Greco-Persian wars he was not lying; that's the name he knew the Greek's adversaries by (and it was not a name of denigration, being based on the name of the locale of Fars). Since most of our history is based on Western literary sources (which is unfortunate, but that's the way it is), I really think it will be exceedingly unwise to redact backwards. But let's have this discussion in the meta thread I opened: http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/412/ancient-iran-persia-tags

Comment: @FelixGoldberg You are welcome! It doesn't bother me but doesn't make sense as well because we are talking about history here by our information about it so I do not know why if you are not satisfied because of a frank but accurate writing by an Iranian about her country, you refer it to the writer! :))

Comment: Sorry it seems you misunderstood me! I am not talking why you call Iran, the Persia as I wrote for you it is not important what the name is but it is important what an old and glorious civilization is behind this or that name. I wrote for you the roots of this kind of naming which is in politics not history. Anyway I like both names. Most of the time I call myself Persian. I answered the question like the others but with different information. Thanks! ;)

Comment: @Felix Goldberg Also Parthia is a cognate to Persia.

Comment: @Anixx Parthia refers to one of many different Iranian ethnics which were living in this big old complicated land. Surely there are many others too but none of them can be used instead of ancient-iran because of a very simple reasoning that is ancient Iran includes all of them not some or one.